# Python: how to move the characters via index?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, indexing

I have 2 arrays `encryted_message = []` and `index_shuffle = []`. The `encryted_message = []` is the array that will take in the user input and split the words into separate characters, the `index_shuffle = []` will keep track of the index number of each characters in `encryted_message = []`

I have already done the programming that takes the user input and adds it to the 2 arrays as mentioned above.

```
encryted_message = []
index_shuffle = []

User_input = input("Type your message here: ")

char_split = list(map(list,User_input))

for char in char_split:
    for charfinal in char:
        encryted_message.append(charfinal)
        
for i,element in enumerate (encryted_message):
        index_shuffle.append(i)
```

This is the output of the code above:

```
Type your message here: hello
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

if you notice that the `index_shuffle = []` index numbers will be determined depending on how many characters are in the `encryted_message = []`.

What I would like the outcome of the next step to be is this:

the index of characters in `encryted_message = []` (['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']) will need to be shuffled around based on the  `index_shuffle = []` ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

I am trying to encrypt the message using the `index_shuffle = []`. Which I am not sure how to do.

What I mean by shuffle is this:

['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'] - normal text
['o', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'h'] - shuffled based on `index_shuffle = []` (This example is not accurate but to it's to give you an idea of what I am trying to achieve)

Comment: What do you mean by shuffling based on `index_shuffle`?

Comment: Why on earth are you doing `char_split = list(map(list,User_input))` and then doing a nested `for` loop to extract each char and put it into another list? Just do `encryted_message = list(User_input)`.

Comment: @Unmitigated updated the question what I mean by ``index_shuffle``

Comment: Your shuffled text has two `e`s and no `o`. Are you just trying to reverse the order of `encrypted_message`? It's still not clear at all what you're trying to achieve, and why you need a separate list to track indices.

Comment: Not trying to reverse the index of encrypted_message  but shuffle the index based on the numbers in index_shuffle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure I understand the question, but perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
text = 'hello'

letter_index = dict(zip(range(len(text)), text))

original_index = list(range(len(text)))

shuffled_index = random.sample(original_index, len(text))

shuffled_string = ''.join([letter_index[index] for index in shuffled_index])
```